# Can a Fortran module override a subroutine in another module?

Tags: oop, module, fortran, overriding

(BTW, this does not involve functions in derived types.)

I want to do something like the following.  I have `module test1`:

> cat test_mod_1.F90

```
module test1

        contains

                subroutine sub1()
                       ! do interesting stuff that any inheriting module
                       ! will want to do ....
                       ! then do something specific to this module:
                        call sub2()
                end subroutine sub1

                subroutine sub2()
                        print *, "I am test1"
                end subroutine sub2

end module test1
```

`test1` is used by `module test2`:

```
> cat test_mod_2.F90
module test2


        use test1, test1_sub2 => sub2

        contains

                subroutine sub2()
                        print *,"I am test2"
                end subroutine sub2

end module test2
```

(By the way, without the "=>" line, `test2` won't even compile.)

Then I have a main program that uses `test2`, not `test1`:

```
> cat testmain.F90
program testmain
        use test2
        call sub1()
end program
```

I want to get the message "I am test2," but things don't work out:

```
> gfortran -o tester test_mod_1.F90 test_mod_2.F90 testmain.F90
> ./tester
 I am test1
```

Is there any way to convince the main program to use `test2`'s `sub2()` instead of `test1`'s?

Comment: Why do you want to "override" instead of something like having the subroutine to call an argument of `sub1`?

Comment: @francescalus  The idea is that sub1() does alot of work that it can be expected any inheriting module will need, which I don't want to have to copy into other modules.  But then there will be specific stuff that inheriting modules will have to do that will be different from what the parent module does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

If you want customisable behaviour in sub1 that is best described by a user provided procedure, then pass a user provided procedure as an argument.

```
module test1
  implicit none
contains
  subroutine sub1(sub2_override)
    ! Declare sub2_override to be a optional dummy procedure that 
    ! has the same interface as the procedure known as sub2.  
    !
    ! Actual procedures associated with this dummy must having matching 
    ! characteristics.
    procedure(sub2), optional :: sub2_override
    
    !...
    if (present(sub2_override)) then
      call sub2_override
    else
      call sub2
    end if
  end subroutine sub1
  
  subroutine sub2
    print *, "I am test1"
  end subroutine sub2
end module test1

program testmain
  use test1
  implicit none
  call sub1
  call sub1(my_sub2)
contains
  subroutine my_sub2
    print *, "I am my_sub2"
  end subroutine my_sub2
end program testmain
```

Comment: If you don't mind me showing my ignorance, what does `procedure(sub2) ...` mean?  Obviously it's saying that `sub2_override` is a procedure, but other than that ... ?  Thanks.

Comment: @bob.sacamento It's written in the comments: it's saying that the arguments of `sub2_override` have to be the same as the arguments of `sub2` (that is, in the present case, no argument)

Comment: The description of the procedure declaration statement was added to the source code in the answer as a result of bob's question.